# ArgumentException when instantiating bitmap from stream

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I've written some code to import content from my Blogger blog. Once I've downloaded all of the HTML content, I go through the image tags and download the corresponding images. In a significant number of cases, System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream is throwing an ArgumentException. The URL I'm downloading from looks good and it serves up an image as expected (here's the URL for one of the problem images: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_tSWCyhtOc38/SgIPcctWRZI/AAAAAAAAAGg/2LLnVPxsogI/s1600-h/IMG_3590.jpg).

```
    private static System.Drawing.Image DownloadImage(string source)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image image = null;

        // used to fetch content
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // used to store image data
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            // fetch the image
            var imageStream = client.GetStreamAsync(source).Result;

            // instantiate a system.drawing.image from the data
            image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(imageStream, false, false);

            // save the image data to a memory stream
            image.Save(memoryStream, image.RawFormat);
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", exception.Message, source);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException exception)
        {
            // sometimes, an image will link to a web page, resulting in this exception
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", exception.Message, source);
        }
        catch (AggregateException exception)
        {
            // sometimes, an image src will throw a 404
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", exception.Message, source);
        }
        finally
        {
            // clean up our disposable resources
            client.Dispose();
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }

        return image;
    }
```

Any idea why an ArgumentException is getting thrown here?

EDIT: It occurred to me that it could be a proxy issue, so I added the following to my web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Adding that section hasn't made any difference, however.

EDIT: This code is called from the context of an EF database initializer. Here's a stack trace:

> Web.dll!Web.Models.Initializer.DownloadImage(string source) Line 234    C#
>       Web.dll!Web.Models.Initializer.DownloadImagesForPost.AnonymousMethod__5(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode tag) Line 126 + 0x8 bytes  C#
>       [External Code] 
>       Web.dll!Web.Models.Initializer.DownloadImagesForPost(Web.Models.Post post) Line 119 + 0x34 bytes    C#
>       Web.dll!Web.Models.Initializer.Seed(Web.Models.FarmersMarketContext context) Line 320 + 0xb bytes   C#
>       [External Code] 
>       App_Web_l2h4tcej.dll!ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() Line 28 + 0x15 bytes   C#
>       [External Code]

Comment: Are you sure that the source of the image is always a valid URI? Sometimes it could be a relative address, which makes sense to the Blogger path but not to retrieve using HttpClient.

Comment: Ok, I've just read your entire question, sorry for the useless comment.

Comment: A Stacktrace would be helpful to pinpoint the cause, but off the top of my head I would suggest the `imageStream` is malformed in some way.

Comment: @xiy, I've added the call stack, but there's nothing particularly interesting there. The image renders fine in IE 10 & Chrome. And, if I download it to my local disk, it opens fine in Paint.NET.

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6.aspx), it'll throw an `ArgumentException` if the image format isn't valid. Try setting the final parameter as true (it validates the stream) and see what happens.

Comment: @xiy, yes, I tried passing both true and false for the validation parameter and it doesn't have any effect on the outcome.

Comment: Then it sounds like it's possibly just HTTP inconsistency. If that's the case and the Image renders fine then just catch the ArgumentException and allow it to pass. It could also be caused by this note, however: `The Image class does not support alpha transparency in bitmaps. To enable alpha transparency, use PNG images with 32 bits per pixel.`

Comment: @xiy, I can't just eat the exception because the image doesn't get instantiated - so I lose the image. I added some code to check the response headers and noticed that, in the case of the images that I can't construct from the stream, they're coming back as text/html rather than image/jpeg - seems like a bug in Blogger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found the issue. It turns out that, in some cases, Blogger references an HTML page that renders an image rather than referencing the image itself. So, the response in that case isn't a valid image. I've added code to check the response headers before attempting to save the image data and that's fixed the problem. For the benefit of anyone else who hits this issue, here's the updated code:

```
    private static System.Drawing.Image DownloadImage(string source)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image image = null;

        // used to fetch content
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // used to store image data
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            // Blogger tacks on a -h to an image Url to link to an HTML page instead
            if (source.Contains("-h/"))
                source = source.Replace("-h/", "/");

            // fetch the image
            var response = client.GetAsync(source).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;

            if (!contentType.StartsWith("image/"))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(contentType);
                throw new ArgumentException("Specified source did not return an image");
            }

            var imageStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

            // instantiate a system.drawing.image from the data
            image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(imageStream, true, true);

            // save the image data to a memory stream
            image.Save(memoryStream, image.RawFormat);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException exception)
        {
            // sometimes, we'll get a 404 or other unexpected response
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", exception.Message, source);
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", exception.Message, source);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException exception)
        {
            // sometimes, an image will link to a web page, resulting in this exception
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", exception.Message, source);
        }
        finally
        {
            // clean up our disposable resources
            client.Dispose();
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }

        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Aha, as I thought. You could easily delve into the response and dig out the Image from that in that case. Upvote for detective work :]

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with another issue, I think you fixed it by accident.  Unfortunately, the GDI+ exceptions are not very good and they often don't tell you what the real problem is.

One of the obscure tidbits in the Image.FromStream() implementation is that GDI+ uses the stream's Seek() method while loading the bitmap from the stream.  This will however only work well when the stream permits seeking, its CanSeek property must return true.  This is in general not the case for network streams, not enough buffering is provided to allow arbitrary seeks.

Which is an issue with HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(), it's MSDN Library document says:

> This method does not buffer the stream

While the working version you wrote uses HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync(), it's MSDN Library documentation says:

> The returned Task object will complete after all of the content has been written as a byte array

So your first version doesn't work because the stream's CanSeek property is false, the second version works because the entire response is read into a byte array which permits seeking.  The universal solution is to slurp the stream into a MemoryStream first.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. That was very likely an issue as well, though not exactly the issue I was wrestling with. If this was really a problem, I would have expected other images to fail as well.